# Allow WordPress users to 'follow' RSS feeds from blog authors

Tags: rss

I have a WordPress blog that allows users to register. Each user will have their own profile page that has their picture and various information.

I'd like users to be able to subscribe to RSS feeds in the WordPress blog such as feeds from categories and tags by clicking a "follow" button. Then the feeds would automatically appear on the User's Profile page. Then I'd like the option for the users to be able to unsubscribe to the feeds (unfollow) so it stops appearing on their profile page if they want.

Is that possible? Can someone help me out with some code or a plugin? I looked everywhere and can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is append `/feed/` to the end of `get_author_posts_url()`, e.g.:

```
<?php
$author_feed_link = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author() ) . '/feed/';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $author_feed_link; ?>">Author RSS Feed</a>
```

Codex ref: [get_author_posts_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url), [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author)

Note that `get_the_author()` must be used within the Loop; otherwise, you'll have to have some other means of getting the Author's user ID.

Comment: I'm believe that's not what he is asking for. he wants to display which feed each user is subscribe to so that's an nice answer but not the right one for the question.

Comment: You know, you're right... let me re-think that...

Comment: a simple way to do that is to create an array with the tags and categories ids and store it in the user meta.